# v-on:click problem if the elements has another element inside

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am dealing with the problem of my click event in vue js. I made a click even on element that has another element inside it.

Here's my code:

```
<span class="pull-down-controller" @click="pullDown($event)">
     <span class="indicator">－</span> Controller
</span>
```

in the frontend it will show `－ Controller`
if I click the word Controller it will call the specified function which is `pullDown()` but why is it whenever I click the indicator or the minus symbol, it will not do anything even if it is inside the `<span>` where I put the `@click` event?

The reason why I put a `<span>` inside it so I can change the symbol to `＋` using jquery.

thanks!

Comment: I prefer you to use anchor tag <a> for you click.  or maybe if you want to pursue that span. try to put css with a style of block of the first span.

Comment: I changed to <a> and tried your other advice, still not working

Comment: can you show to me how your css done to that pull-down-controller and indicator ?

Answer (score 1):

No need for jQuery, Vue's reactivity provides all you need:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <span @click="pullDown" style="font-size: 48px;">
     <span>{{ indicator }}</span> Controller
</span>
`,
  data () {
    return {
      expanded: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    indicator () {
      return this.expanded ? '+' : '-'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    pullDown (event) {
      this.expanded = !this.expanded
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: what if it has 3 or more controller or div with the controller? is all the indicator affect?

Comment: You'd use an array to manage the state of multiple controllers instead of a single boolean property.

Comment: but do you know the problem about my original question? thanks!

Comment: Problem lies in the fact that Vue is using virtual DOM. And every changes you are doing in Vue, changes the virtual DOM, not the browser DOM. Browser DOM is then automatically, on demand, patched / merged with the virtual DOM copy. But with jQuery you are changing browser DOM directly, not the virtual DOM. So, Vue have no clue about this changes, because Vue see virtual DOM only. You should use jQuery with Vue only if you know how to do it, because they are incompatible by default.